# Assigning data to groups based on percentage splits for count and total balance allocated

Tags: sql-server

This might be a nice Friday afternoon SQL Puzzle for someone? ;D

I have a requirement for assigning customers to debt collection agencies (DCAs).  Basically we agree a split, e.g. 65%:35%, or 50%:50%, or even 60%:30%:10% (as in my example) where the percentages govern two things:

- the percentage of the number of customers assigned to each DCA;
- the total percentage of debt assigned to each DCA.

My challenge is to come up with the best match I can find, e.g. if I had four customers:

- Customer A owes £100;
- Customer B owes £500;
- Customer C owes £550;
- Customer D owes £50.

The "ideal" match for a 50%:50% split would be:

DCA 1
- Customers A and B = 2 customers with a total debt of £600;

DCA 2
- Customers C and D = 2 customers with a total debt of £600.

...and a "bad" match would be:

DCA 1
- Customers A and D = 2 customers with a total debt of £150;

DCA 2
- Customers B and C = 2 customers with a total debt of £1050.

I can think of ways to solve this problem in .NET, and also "loop" based solutions for SQL scripts.  These all work on the logic:

- make random assignments by numbers only, i.e. put the right number of customers in each DCA "bucket", but don't attempt to split the balance properly;
- does swapping one customer with another in a different bucket improve the balance assignment?  If it does swap them;
- repeat until all swaps have been considered.

I can't come up with a set-based solution to the problem.

Here is some test data, and a sample of what I have tried so far:

```
--Create some test data
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    account_number VARCHAR(50),
    account_balance NUMERIC(19,2));
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '1', 100;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '2', 1200;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '3', 500;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '4', 300;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '5', 200;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '6', 250;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '7', 400;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '8', 300;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '9', 280;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '10', 100;

--Define the split by debt collection agency
DECLARE @split TABLE (
    dca VARCHAR(10),
    dca_split_percentage INT);
INSERT INTO @split SELECT 'dca1', 60;
INSERT INTO @split SELECT 'dca2', 30;
INSERT INTO @split SELECT 'dca3', 10;

--Somewhere to store the results
DECLARE @results TABLE (
    dca VARCHAR(10),
    account_number VARCHAR(50),
    account_balance NUMERIC(19,2));

--Populate the results
WITH DCASplit AS (
    SELECT dca, dca_split_percentage / 100.0 AS percentage FROM @split),
DCAOrdered AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dca) AS dca_id FROM DCASplit),
Customers AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS customer_count FROM @table),
Random AS (
    SELECT *, NEWID() AS random FROM @table),
Ordered AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY random) AS order_id FROM Random),
Splits AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 d.dca_id, d.dca, 1 AS start_id, CONVERT(INT, c.customer_count * d.percentage) AS end_id FROM DCAOrdered d CROSS JOIN Customers c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.dca_id, d.dca, s.end_id + 1 AS start_id, CONVERT(INT, s.end_id + c.customer_count * d.percentage) AS end_id FROM Splits s INNER JOIN DCAOrdered d ON d.dca_id = s.dca_id + 1 CROSS JOIN Customers c)
INSERT INTO
    @results
SELECT
    d.dca,
    o.account_number,
    o.account_balance
FROM
    DCAOrdered d
    INNER JOIN Splits s ON s.dca_id = d.dca_id
    INNER JOIN Ordered o ON o.order_id BETWEEN s.start_id AND s.end_id;

--Show the raw results
SELECT * FROM @results;

--Show the aggregated results
WITH total_debt AS (SELECT SUM(account_balance) AS total_balance FROM @results)
SELECT r.dca, COUNT(*) AS customers, SUM(r.account_balance), SUM(r.account_balance) / t.total_balance AS percentage_debt FROM @results r CROSS JOIN total_debt t GROUP BY r.dca, t.total_balance;
```

I know this works for splitting by the number of customers, but it makes no attempt to try and split out the balances using the percentage split.  In fact the split is entirely random each time the script runs.

For example, I got these results from one run:

```
dca account_number  account_balance
dca1    8   £300.00
dca1    2   £1200.00
dca1    5   £200.00
dca1    3   £500.00
dca1    9   £280.00
dca1    6   £250.00
dca2    10  £100.00
dca2    7   £400.00
dca2    1   £100.00
dca3    4   £300.00
```

But when I add that all up I get:

```
dca customers   debt_assigned   percentage_debt
dca1    6   £2730.00        75%
dca2    3   £600.00         17%
dca3    1   £300.00         8%
```

i.e. the 60:30:10 split is fine for customer counts, but I have assigned 75% of the debt to DCA1 when they should only be getting 60%, etc.

I could use a "brute force" solution, which would be to run that query multiple times, then pick the results set with the closest match by debt.  However, the performance of that would be poor, it still wouldn't guarantee I would get the "best split", and I am dealing with hundreds of thousands of customers in real life.

Any ideas for how to solve this problem in a single set-based query?

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: Any version you want, up to and including 2016.  I imagine something could be done with LEAD and LAG, but I couldn't get much further than that.

Comment: Hi richard, I remember i had to do something similar with "Buckets of Mortgages" and I ended up using 2 Cursors - 1 from the top & 1 from the bottom. I remember thinking that there must be a set based query though! It does sound a bit like the classic knapsack problem.